# Title of book about humanity seeing their lives X years in the future due to astronomical event

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I have recently been recommended a book, but I don't remember its title, nor its author. It's about an astronomical event that makes all humanity experience/see their lives some exact number of years in the future for a short moment.

Afterwards, everybody goes back to the present and we are presented with the stories of certain individuals who change their lives based on the information they have about the future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Possibly [Flashforward](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/337132.Flashforward:) by Robert J Sawyer? Physics experiment rather than astronomical event, but gave people a vision of their futures, then follows how they responded to that knowledge.

> Two minutes and seventeen seconds that changed the world
>
> Suddenly, without warning, all seven billion people on Earth black out for more than two minutes. Millions die as planes fall from the sky, people tumble down staircases, and cars plow into each other.
>
> But that’s the least of the survivors’ challenges. During the blackout, everyone experienced a glimpse of what his or her future holds—and the interlocking mosaic of these visions threatens to unravel the present.

Comment: Also a short lived TV series - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashForward

Comment: In the book, I'm pretty sure it was a particle collider experiment thay happened to coincide with an astronomical event that resulted in the flash forward. So you're both right-ish.

Comment: Ah, could be - long time since I read it and could easily have forgotten that detail. Thanks!